# Ramification concept in complex analysis and algebraic number theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-surfaces, ramification

I have a question about the connection between the concept of ramification/branching out for Riemann surfaces and algebraic number theory:

1. In the theory of Riemann surfaces we have following nomenclature:

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a holomorphic map between Piemann surfaces $X,Y$ and $x_i \in f^{-1}(y)=\{x_1,x_2,..., x_n \}$ a point in the fiber of $y \in Y$.

Then we say that $x_i$ has ramification index $r_i$ if locally (concretely on sufficient small open enviroments $x_i \in U_i \subset X, y \in V_y \subset  Y$) the holomorphic map$f$ "behaves" like $ x \mapsto x^{r_i}$

Rmk: by "locally" I mean that we have chart maps $\phi_{x_i}:\mathbb{C} \to U_i, \phi_{y}:\mathbb{C} \to U_y$ such that $\phi_{y}^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi_{x_i}: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is given by $ x \mapsto x^{r_i}$

2. On the other hand we consider an extension of number fields $K \subset L$ and take a prime $p \subset O_K$ from the ring of integers then it splits in $O_L$ via $p O_L= p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}...p_n^{r_n}O_L$ and analogously we can $r_i$ the ramification index of $p_i$ over $p$.

My question is if there exist a concrete construction between Riemann surfaces and number fields (or other class of fields where the concept of braches & ramifications of primes holds) where the both ramification numbers $e_i$ coinside in meaningsful sense.

My ideas: On order to connect points with primes it seems reasonable to impose the connection by a sheaf. My naive guess for a candidate would be the sheaf $O_x^{\text{an}}$ of analytic functions of $X$ resp $Y$. Then $f$ induces a sheaf morphism $O_Y \to f_*O_X$ and on level of stalks $O_{Y,y} =O_{Y,f(x)} \to O_{X,x_i}$.

But here I face some problems. For example since $f$ induce a morphism of ***ringed spaces*** the maximal ideal $m_y$ is mapped on maximal ideal $m_{x_i}$ so I can't expect any "ramification bahavior" like $m_yO_{X,x_i}= m_{x_i}^{r_i}O_{X,x_i}$.

Is there nevertheless a way to obtain a connection between this two ramification concepts 1. and 2. or do they share the same nomenclature just because of "stuctural" analogy?

Comment: > since $f$ induce a morphism of ringed spaces the maximal ideal  $\mathfrak m_y$ is mapped on maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_{x_i}$

This is false, any morphism of complex-analytic spaces induces a morphism of locally ringed spaces, this means that a natural morphism $\mathcal O_{Y, f(x)} \to \mathcal O_{X,x}$ is local, in other words this means that $\mathfrak m_{f(x)}$ is mapped into (not onto!) $\mathfrak m_x$. Since for a $1$-dimensional smooth complex analytic space the local rings $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ are DVRs (it may require a proof depending on your definitions)...

Comment: ... we see that $\mathfrak m_{f(x)} \mathcal O_{X,x}$ must be some power of an ideal $\mathfrak m_x$. This is exactly the index of ramification. You can give a "uniform definition" of ramification (but it is essentially useless) by considering both $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal O_L$ and Riemann surfaces as elements of the ambient category of locally ringed spaces (naturally one leaves in the world of schemes, and the other in the world of complex-analytic spaces). I think this answers your question, but it is basically useless in practice.

Comment: @gdb: but why these two ramification numbers coinside?

Comment: It’s sufficient to do the calculation for the map $x \mapsto x^n$, where it is obvious: the maximal ideal of the image is generated by $x^n$, the $n$th power of the maximal ideal of the source.

Comment: If $O_K$ is a Dedekind domain with field of fractions $K$ and $L$ is a finite extension of $K$ and $O_L$ is the integral closure then (nonzero) prime ideals in $O_K$ factor as products of powers of primes in $O_L$, and the exponents can be called ramification indices. The number-field case that you mention is a special case of this. Another special case is when $O_K$ is the coordinate ring of a smooth affine complex algebraic curve $Y$. In this case $O_L$ is the coordinate ring of another such curve $X$. Analytically the map $X\to Y$ looks like $x\mapsto x^r$ at a point with index $r$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie:...and here you use implicitely a category equivalence (?) between smooth affine complex algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces? Intuitively it seems to work but I still haven't found a source which constructs rigorously this correspondence between s.a.c.a. curves and Riemann surfaces in satisfying manner. Could you recommend something?